# SNK.test : How to add factor levels to the "groups" argument

Tags: r

I've run an SNK.test on a dataset and here below  my columns and the model I've used :

```
response = c (28.16, 29.36, 35.44, 37.1, 4.9, 5, 5.12, 8.8958333, 11.1, 8.5, 4.48, 3.28, 3.92, 8.24, 1.5714285, 6.02, 3.14, 2.84, 5.54, 3.24, 12.62, 7.66, 15.06, 2.2857142, 1.48, 1.94, 7.22, 1.48, 5.14, 1.66, 15.66, 2.98, 4.26, 0.2653061, 10.26, 23.02, 4.12, 0.64, 10.16, 1.36, 3.22, 5.2448979, 0.28, 0.26, 1.2653061, 0.7826086, 0.46, 0.78)
trt = c (001, 001, 001, 001,  002, 002, 002, 002,  003, 003, 003, 003, 004, 004, 004, 004, 005, 005, 005, 005, 006, 006, 006, 006, 007, 007, 007, 007, 008, 008, 008, 008, 009, 009, 009, 009, 010, 010, 010, 010,  011, 011, 011, 011, 012, 012, 012, 012
rep = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)  
df <- data.frame(response, trt, rep)
df$response <- as.numeric(df$response)
df$trt <- as.factor(df$trt)
df$rep <- as.factor(df$rep)
model <- aov(response ~ trt + rep, data = df)
mc_SNK <- SNK.test(model,"trt", console=TRUE, group = TRUE)
```

My target is to get the groups column and joinging it later to the original dataset. For that I need to associate this column "groups" from mc_SNK$groups to the "trt" levels that I need for this JOIN step. My problem is that the argument "groups" doesn't have this column and I see that the output in this table is ordered by "response" dercreasing order, and my need is to order it by "trt" number increasing order, or at least having this column "trt" in this argument.
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The "ordering" of factors is done by the lexical ordering of factor levels by default but your trt argument should  be a character variable to start with. Otherwise 010 will be less than 004 since they will be input as numeric and only later be coerced to factor levels and "10" is less than "4" when considered alphabetically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+order+factor+levels